# How to create a self-signed cert for a local hosted wss:// server

Tags: ssl, websocket, x509certificate

I am attempting to create a windows service that opens a secure web socket and listens for connections on a certain port (wss://localhost:1234). The sample code includes referencing a certificate for the server to use:

```
var serverCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, "mypassword");
```

This works fine.

The issue happens when the a client attempts to connected:

```
using (SslStream n = new SslStream(client.TcpClientInstance.GetStream()))
{
   n.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, clientCertificateRequired: false, enabledSslProtocols: System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12, checkCertificateRevocation: false);
```

This line errors out with a generic "A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception", "InnerException = {"An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate"}":

This occurs with a self-signed cert registered in the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities.

Interestingly enough if I use the generic localhost cert generated by Visual Studio it works.

Any thoughts welcome.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Might solve your issue.

Create a sub-domain like sub-domain.domain.com ( using your actual domain )
With an A record to 127.0.0.1
Request a SSL certificate for sub-domain.domain.com

When you open a connection to sub-domain.domain.com it will be valid and should resolve to 127.0.0.1 which is where your "server" is listening.